# Number Theory Question: $x^2-33y^3=10$ no solutions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I've been struggling to get my head around this for a while!

Show that:

$x^2 - 33y^3 = 10$

has no integral solutions

Comment: I am guessing that you mean there are no INTEGER solutions

Comment: @stackErr certainly. otherwise $\sqrt{10},0$ is certainly *one* solution. There are a lot more of course.

Answer (score 9):

Check modulo $11$. 10 is not a quadratic residue modulo $11$

Taking the equation modulo $11$ and noting that $33$ is divisble by $11$.

$$x^2\equiv 10\pmod{11}$$

Comment: Nope, mod 4 does not work.

Comment: @DanielFischer but the question has $33y^3\equiv y^3$

Comment: @Sabyasachi Ah, didn't see that.

Comment: @Sabyasachi could you extend this, I'm still struggling to understand how I should go about solving the question

Comment: @user146650 edited.